# How can I improve the code in which I use function extensions at present in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I hope to place a line in new coordinate system, the new origin coordinate is `val orig=Point(100,50)`, the new X axis is to right, and new Y axis is to up.

At present, I use function extensions, just like Code A.

I find it's not good, there are many repeated code such as `.toX(orig)`, `.toY(orig)`.

How can I design the data structure to improve the code？

**Code A**

```
val orig=Point(100,50)

drawIntoCanvas {
    it.drawLine(
          Offset(x = 0f.toX(orig), y = 0f.toY(orig)),
          Offset(x = (size.width- 200).toX(orig), y = 0f.toY(orig)),
          axisPaint
    )
        
    val shadowPath = Path()
    val data =  maxCountList.toList()
    val step= 20       
    for (i in data.indices){
       shadowPath.lineTo((orignX+step*i).toX(orig),data[i].toFloat().toY(orig))
    }
    shadowPath.close()
    it.drawPath(shadowPath,pathPaint)
    
    it.nativeCanvas.drawText("Max",50f.toX(orig), 100f.toY(orig), textPaint)
}


fun Float.toX(originCoordinate: Point) : Float {
    return originCoordinate.x+this
}

fun Float.toY(originCoordinate: Point): Float {
    return originCoordinate.y-this
}
```

**Ended**

The [Can I pass a delegated to a variable in Kotlin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494255/can-i-pass-a-delegated-to-a-variable-in-kotlin) is perfect solution!

```
data class MyPoint(val x: Float, val y: Float) {
    val Float.toXX: Float get() = x + this
    val Float.toYY: Float get() = y - this
}

// In a function:
val orig = MyPoint(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
orig.run {
    drawPath.moveTo(10.0f.toXX, 20.0f.toYY)
    drawPath.moveTo(5.0f.toXX, 80.0f.toYY)
    drawPath.moveTo(1.0f.toXX, 3.0f.toYY)
}
```

Comment: The origin from which you are drawing seems like something the `it` in `it.drawLine` should know about, don't you think? How about designing it so that you can do `it.move(dx = 100, dy = 50)` and then `drawLine` can just have `(0, 0, size.width - 200, 0)` as arguments. Do you have control over `it`?

Comment: What class is `it` and what is Offset? Can you show the code of these classes? If you want to work with float coordinates, why use the Point class at all?

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Answer (score 5):

I would say that the simplest way would be to actually *make* your origin the actual origin of the canvas while drawing, by translating the canvas:

```
fun Canvas.withTranslation(x: Float, y: Float, block: (Canvas) -> Unit) {
    withSave {
        translate(x, y)
        block(this)
    }
}

fun DrawScope.drawIntoCanvasWithOrigin(origin: PointF, block: (Canvas) -> Unit) {
    drawIntoCanvas {
        it.withTranslation(origin.x, origin.y) { canvas ->
            block(canvas)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you do not need to add the origin to every single value because everything is already relative to your origin, and you can just write:

```
val orig=Point(100,50)

drawIntoCanvasWithOrigin(orig.toPointF()) {
    it.drawLine(
          Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
          Offset(x = size.width- 200, y = 0f),
          axisPaint
    )
        
    val shadowPath = Path()
    val data =  maxCountList.toList()
    val step= 20       
    for (i in data.indices){
       shadowPath.lineTo(orignX+step*i,data[i].toFloat())
    }
    shadowPath.close()
    it.drawPath(shadowPath,pathPaint)
    
    it.nativeCanvas.drawText("Max",50f, 100f, textPaint)
}
```

Taking into account your comment that you want to mirror the y-axis at the defined point of origin, we can extend the code accordingly:

```
fun Canvas.withScale(x: Float, y: Float, block: (Canvas) -> Unit) {
    withSave {
        scale(x, y)
        block(this)
    }
}

fun DrawScope.drawIntoCanvasWithOrigin(origin: PointF, block: (Canvas) -> Unit) {
    drawIntoCanvas {
        it.withTranslation(origin.x, origin.y) { canvasAtOrigin ->
            canvasAtOrigin.withScale(1.0f, -1.0f) { mirroredCanvas ->
                block(mirroredCanvas)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks！ But your code can't get the correct result, you know my code is `fun Float.toY(originCoordinate: Point): Float {return originCoordinate.y-this}` for Y axis, so New Y axis is a Mirror of original Y axis.

Comment: And X axia is normal `fun Float.toX(originCoordinate: Point) : Float { return originCoordinate.x+this }`

Comment: @HelloCW Good to know, that wasn't clear from the question. I modified my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But `fun DrawScope.drawIntoCanvasWithOrigin(...){it.withTranslation(origin.x, origin.y) ...}` can't be compiled

Comment: @HelloCW Yes, you are right, everything has to be wrapped inside `drawIntoCanvas`. I modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But it's  not still be compiled

Comment: It displays the error `Unresolved reference: withTranslation` with your updated code

Comment: @HelloCW I am really sorry for that, I am not an Android developer and developed the solution so far "in the dark" using only Google. I did now install an Android SDK and realized that there are different `Canvas` classes (the canvas and its nativeCanvas), and `withTranslation` as well as `withScale` are defined for the "wrong" `Canvas` class. Therefore, it is necessary to define these functions for the right `Canvas` class ourselves. I modified the answer.

Comment: Thanks! But I have to say your code can't handle `drawText`,  text is mirrored by your code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494255/can-i-pass-a-delegated-to-a-variable-in-kotlin is great solution!

Answer (score 1):

I second Ivo that the extension functions do not really increase readability. What I would do is to not focus on x and y, but on the Points. An offset in a two-dimensional layout is a new Point, so you're probably better off doing something like this:

```
fun Point.offset(offsetX: Float, offsetY: Float): Point {
  return Point(this.x + offsetX, this.y + offsetY)
}
```

And you use it like this:

```
it.drawLine(
  orig.offset(0f, 0f),   // which is of course the same as: orig
  orig.offset(size.width - 200f, 0f),
  axisPaint
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But you know that your code can't handle other draw functions  such as `Path().moveTo(x,y)`,  `it.nativeCanvas.drawText(x,y....)` ..

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my modified content in the question? 
I need to draw line, text and polygon with drawIntoCanvas based new coordinate system.
Your code can only handle the function `drawLine`, and your code can't handle other functions such as `drawText`, `drawPath`.

Comment: I still do not understand. My suggested code is for calculating a new point at a certain offset. You then have a new point with an x value and a y value, which you can use as you wish. The idea is to take the calculation of an argument for a function parameter x or y out of the function call. So you would do something like this for drawLine: 
_val toPoint = startPoint.offset(originX + step * i, data[i]); 
shadowPath.lineTo(toPoint.x, toPoint, y)_.

Comment: Thanks! Could you repleace Code A with your solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question and answer are kind of subjective, but in my opinion do the extensions not add anything. And actually make it unnecessarily complex.

Just writing

```
it.drawLine(
    Offset(x = orig.x + 0f, y = orig.y + 0f),
    Offset(x = orig.x + (size.width- 200), y = orig.y - 0f),
    axisPaint
)
```

is better in my opinion. Also no point to add 0f to it so for this example I would just go with

```
it.drawLine(
    Offset(x = orig.x, y = orig.y),
    Offset(x = orig.x + (size.width- 200), y = orig.y),
    axisPaint
)
```

Comment: Thanks! But `(size.width- 200).toX(orig)` is easy to understand than `orig.x + (size.width- 200)` .

Comment: And more, your code will be more complex if I need to rotation coordinate system.

Comment: And more, if I need to draw many lines based new coordinate system,  maybe your code is not good.