# Can I pass a delegated to a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I use Code A to add a Extensions for Float type, so I can use it with Code B.

But Code B has many repeated code, and it's not easy to use.

So I try to write Code C to improve it, but Android Studio can't compile it.

1: How can I fix Code C?

2: Is there other way to improve Code A and Code B?

**Code A**

```
fun Float.toX(originCoordinate: MyPoint) :Float {
    return originCoordinate.x+this
}

fun Float.toY(originCoordinate: MyPoint):Float {
    return originCoordinate.y-this
}

class MyPoint (val x:Float, val y: Float)
```

**Code B**

```
val orig = MyPoint(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)

drawPath.moveTo(10.0f.toX(orig), 20.0f.toY(orig))
drawPath.moveTo(5.0f.toX(orig), 80.0f.toY(orig))
drawPath.moveTo(1.0f.toX(orig), 3.0f.toY(orig))
....
```

**Code C**

```
val orig = MyPoint(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)

val toXX = Float.toX(orig)
val toYY = Float.toY(orig)

drawPath.moveTo(10.0f.toXX, 20.0f.toYY)
drawPath.moveTo(5.0f.toXX, 80.0f.toYY)
drawPath.moveTo(1.0f.toXX, 3.0f.toYY)
...
```

Comment: Do you have control over `moveTo` or `drawPath`? If not, then do you mind creating your own `moveTo` function with a slightly different name?

Comment: This looks suspiciously similar to [this other question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71291510/how-can-i-improve-the-code-in-which-i-use-function-extensions-at-present-in-kotl). Can you explain what the difference is?

Comment: Thanks! I don't wish to create my own `moveto` or `drawPath`, I hope to improve the  extensions  `Float.toX(orig) `  of  Float type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to fix Code C. Use `get()` so they are recalculated each time they're accessed. And move `Float.` before the name to make it an extension property. Where you have it is the syntax for calling a function in the `Float` companion object, which of course doesn't exist.

```
// at top level of your class:
var orig = MyPoint(0f, 0f)

private val Float.toXX: Float get() = toX(orig)
private val Float.toYY: Float get() = toY(orig)

// ------

// In a function:
orig = MyPoint(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)

drawPath.moveTo(10.0f.toXX, 20.0f.toYY)
drawPath.moveTo(5.0f.toXX, 80.0f.toYY)
drawPath.moveTo(1.0f.toXX, 3.0f.toYY)
```

---

Here's a completely different approach to the problem. You could define extension properties inside your MyPoint class, and then use them if you are inside a `run` block called on your class:

```
data class MyPoint(val x: Float, val y: Float) {
    val Float.toXX: Float get() = x + this
    val Float.toYY: Float get() = y - this
}

// In a function:
val orig = MyPoint(size.width / 2, size.height / 2)
orig.run {
    drawPath.moveTo(10.0f.toXX, 20.0f.toYY)
    drawPath.moveTo(5.0f.toXX, 80.0f.toYY)
    drawPath.moveTo(1.0f.toXX, 3.0f.toYY)
}
```

Comment: Thank! I think your thinking is great, but I was prompt `Local extension properties are not allowed` with your code.

Comment: Yes, you can't define it inside a function. But you could make `orig` a property and change its value inside your function before you start using `drawPath.moveTo` Or you could change them to extension functions like `fun Float.toXX() = toX(orig)`, but you would have to keep using `()`. I don't know why Kotlin doesn't support local extension properties.

Comment: Thanks! How can I make `orig` a property and change the value of a Float value?

Comment: Thanks! Your code is great, and I think `fun Float.toXX() = toX(orig)` is great for flexible, and I only need keep using `( )` .

Comment: See my update. I came up with one alternative solution in case you're interested.

Comment: Thanks! Your second way can get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks again, the second way is perfect solution !!!